# Bluetooth has short interruptions

Tags: keyboard, wifi, bluetooth, mouse, ping

I am experiencing short interruptions of the Bluetooth connection on my early 2013 MacBook Pro Retina. I have connected my Magic Mouse, my Magic Keyboard and Bluetooth headphones. Every few seconds there is a short interruption resulting in lag of the input devices or a short distortion in the sound. The devices do not get disconnected. The time interval is very short.

What I find peculiar is, when I ping at the same time `ping google.de`, every time the distortion occurs the ping tenfolds just for one iteration.

Has anyone observed similar problems?